# TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags {'serve'} could not be found in SavedModel

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am new to Tensorflow and i'm trying to convert the .pb model I've trained from just using TensorFlow to a TFLITE file.

I am following the provided document (ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/python_api.md).

My code to generate the .pb file is

```
save_dir = "models/"
node_names = [node.name for node in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]
output_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
                               sess=sess,
                               input_graph_def =sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
                               output_node_names=node_names)

# write protobuf to disk
with tf.gfile.GFile('models/saved_model.pb', "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

I am trying to convert with:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(save_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

The error i am getting is:

RuntimeError: MetaGraphDef associated with tags {'serve'} could not be found in SavedModel.

Answer (score 0):

I get a same problem.

In the tensorflow GitHub issues, I found the comments "If it is frozen graph, then you need to provide'input_arrays' and'output_arrays'".

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38080

If you don't know 'input_arrays', 'ouput_arrays' and 'input_shapes', you will find all parameters in this link.

https://netron.app/

Answer (score 0):

The model you are using is a frozen graph, rather than a saved model.

Thus it needs to use a specific importer for the TFLite convertor:

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    model_file,
    input_arrays=[input_name], 
    output_arrays=[output_name],  
)
```